# sanity check: count(*) vs count(pkColumn)

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

Today my boss told me to use `count(pkColumn)` instead of `count(*)`, saying it will be faster. I'm pretty sure this isn't true, but I'm less a DBA than a Java developer so I wanted to check.

I ran some query plans:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Foo";
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT("FooUID") FROM "Foo";
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(1) FROM "Foo";
```

With the results:

```
Aggregate  (cost=1421.01..1421.02 rows=1 width=0)
  ->  Seq Scan on "Foo"  (cost=0.00..1296.81 rows=49681 width=0)

Aggregate  (cost=1421.01..1421.02 rows=1 width=16)
  ->  Seq Scan on "Foo"  (cost=0.00..1296.81 rows=49681 width=16)

Aggregate  (cost=1421.01..1421.02 rows=1 width=0)
  ->  Seq Scan on "Foo"  (cost=0.00..1296.81 rows=49681 width=0)
```

They seem the same. Can someone just confirm that I'm correct about this? I realize this has been discussed for other languages, but PostgreSQL handles `COUNT` differently as I understand, and I couldn't find a PostgreSQL equivalent question.

Note that `"FooUID"` will never be `NULL`.

**EDIT:** using version 9.0.4

Comment: Beware that COUNT(*) and COUNT(Column) are not 100% equivalent. The later won't include any rows in the count where the column you chose is null. Oh and your boss is wrong. That is micro-optimization and if there is any performance benefit it will be negligable.

Comment: @John, I think it should be the same on a primary key column, due to the requirement that PKs are non-NULL. You're right about other columns of course.

Comment: @JohnFx - Thanks for the feedback. It's the PK column so there won't be nulls. Even so it's sounding like there's no reason not to use count(*).

Comment: I noticed that. I mostly mentioned it for anyone else who came across this post later. And frankly, I prefer count(*) because it is resilient to changes in your table structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your boss is misguided (at best).

Yes, PostgreSql (at least the ones I've used, up to 8.1) does treat `count` slightly differently in that it has to go to the actual table to get some information rather than just using the index alone (with [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control), it stores "soft" deletion information in the table so each row has to be retrieved to see if it's been deleted but not yet removed from an index).

But it has to do that regardless of whether you use `*` or `pk_column` for the count. The advantage of using `*` is that the DBMS is free to choose any non-null column for the count, which may result in less disk I/O for the index processing.

If your boss is worried about the performance, there are a couple of possible "tricks" you can use.

First, if you're only interested in the *existence* of rows rather then the *number,* you can use change code like:

```
select count(*) into myCount from myTable where myCondition;
if myCount > 0 then
    do something
end if;
```

into:

```
if exists ( select * from myTable where myCondition ) then
    do something
end if;
```

Secondly, you can use `insert` and `delete` triggers which maintain two counters in a separate table for rows added and rows deleted. You can then work out the rowcount by simply subtracting one from the other. The use of two separate counters prevents serialisation on the insert/delete operations but it's still a massive kludge and probably unnecessary for the vast number of cases.

You also have to periodically scale back the counters (for example, modify `1000 inserts + 200 deletes` to be `800 inserts and 0 deletes`).

Thirdly, you can get an *estimate* of the row count (based on the last analyse operation) by using:

```
select reltuples from pg_class where relname = 'myTable';
```

Comment: Yes, perhaps I was unnecessarily harsh in calling them an idiot, though anyone that puts forward conjecture-without-supporting-evidence as fact is on very shaky ground. Edited the answer to be more kind to our poor dumb cousins in management :-)

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, `count(column)` can be faster than `count(*)` because when the SQL parser parses the `*` it must look up in the catalog what the column names are for the table, which is what `*` represents. By using `count(column)` you potentially avoid this catalog look up.

This "advantage" is so insignificant compared to the reduced readability it causes, and denies the database the chance to optimize your intention by some other mechanism (eg counting an indexed column and thus doing an index-only search).

Use `count(*)`.

Comment: Depending on the version, there may be no index-only searches in PostgreSQL due to the optimisation for MVCC.

Comment: @paxdiablo - using 9.0.4, I'll update the question with that. Thanks to you both for the informative answers!

Comment: @Kublai, I can't find anything in the `>8.1` docs to indicate that `count` method has changed. It still appears to use the table access method.

Comment: @paxdiablo - Sounds good. Thanks for teaching me about the "soft" deletion bit. I had read about `count` being slower in pg but hadn't learned the reasons behind it.

Comment: I don't think `count(*)` will actually go lookup all columns in the table..... that's an urban myth.... `select *` will have to do that to get all columns to return, yes - but not `count(*)`....

Answer (score 1):

#### In PostgreSQL:

- `count(*)` equals `count(PK)`

  As [Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian) has said, there is a little delay in translating the `*` into a field; however there is also a delay in legitimizing `PK` as a valid field.  Regardless, they are negligible performance hits.

#### Additional Reading:

- http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting

#### [PostgreSQL Docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html):

- > Note: Users accustomed to working with other SQL database management systems might be disappointed by the performance of the count aggregate when it is applied to the entire table. A query like:
  >
  > `SELECT count(*) FROM sometable;`
  >
  > will be executed by PostgreSQL using a sequential scan of the entire table.

Comment: @Kublai: I was wrong about the index fields, I found an answer on stackexchange, which said the count(*) does search on indexed, but I started thinking and it was wrong.  Not only is it not in the documentation, but there would be no gain, because the index is meant to speed up filters and in this case you're not filtering anything.  If you were filtering, the index would still be used, so it doesn't matter about using count(field).

Comment: I'm unsure if count(*) is in the SQL spec.  It's possible that years ago it wasn't and DBs like Oracle may have required a specific field name.  So `count(fieldname)` might be more portable between different databases, if that's a requirement you may have.